# Parse XML RSS feed for news ticker

Tags: jquery, xml

I have been using the plug in [jquery.newsticker.js](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/newsticker/) to display a newsticker that fades each node in and out. Previously we'd been using a `<ul>` but now we want to use our xml rss feed file so we don't have to update two files.

My code for the `<ul>` newsticker was as follows

```
$.get(
    "AJAX/tickerContent.php", {}, function(data) {
         $("#ticker").append(data).find("ul").newsTicker();
     }
)
```

Now I need to parse the xml which is set up like this

```
<item>
        <title>New Story Test</title>
        <description>Story 1</description>
        <link>http://www.sit.com/tour</link>
        <pubDate>Tue, 9 Nov 2010 09:32:16 GMT</pubDate>
    </item>
```

and have it output as such `title + <link><description></link> + pubdate`

I can parse the xml but can't get it to work in the ticker function call

```
{
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "RSS/myRSS.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXml
      });

      function parseXml(xml)
        {
          $(xml).find("item").each(function()
          {

            $("#ticker").append(this).find("title").text().newsTicker();
          });
        }
```

how to I unscrew this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#ticker").append(this)
```

`this` is an XML element, you can't append it into an HTML document.

Perhaps you mean something like:

```
<ul id="ticker"></ul>

$(xml).find('item').each(function() {
    var title= $(this).find('title').text();
    $('#ticker').append($('<li>', {text: title}));
});
$('#ticker').newsTicker();
```